# Azure DevOps Pipeline - wildcard not trigger pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to ask you what is a the reason of not running a pipeline after making a commit from Visual Studio to repository located in Azure DevOps? Has trigger in yaml lower priority from trigger builded inside pipeline where default is set to develop (Yaml -GetSource)?

My current yaml code:

```
 trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - feature/*
```

Name of my current branch local/origin:

```
feature/employer-service
```

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: What kind of repository do you Have? Azure Repos Git? Github?

Comment: Hi, Azure Repos Git - but probably I found solution as I had to add yaml file to that branch. Yaml was on other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time, I've found solution:

In order to run pipeline after making commit from repository, you have to add separate yaml file to branch which actually you are pushing.

I had yaml file on develop branch but the necessary was to add a similar yaml file with whole setup to a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

As you found in the comment, if you want the branch to get CI triggers, you need to make sure that the same `azure-pipelines.yml` file exists on the branch.

You can switch to each branch on the pipeline page to check whether the `azure-pipelines.yml` file is included. If it does not exist, you will get the following error.

[image]